# How to align a button in the center according to screensize?

Tags: html, css, button

Is there a way to align a button (or any other object) in the center of the screen (this should work for any size of computer screen)?
I'm doing a project and tried wrapping the button into a div and setting text-align: center, but the button is still off center and I was wondering if there's another way to do that?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `margin: 0 auto` to align the div to the center?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: I've been reading about how to do it and I've been trying all kinds of methods for like an hour now so no, it's not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work.
margin set to auto for the containing div

```css
.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a problem, if you could mark it as correct, thanks :)

Comment: This is a bit fragile since if you change the amount of text within the button, you'll need to manually adjust the width of it's container.  Also, it's hard to verify if the button is truly centered, or just close to it.

Comment: No matter how much text is displayed by the button, it will always be centered. However, your point regarding the width of the container is valid; fortunately, OP asked for a centered button within this "wrapping" container, therefore it is not relevant

Comment: @ReConnected, I can show an example where the button is not centered with your method.  https://jsfiddle.net/8Lqqp0xz/

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah, I see, is this due to possible addition of a scrollbar?

Comment: @ReConnected I don't think so.  You can verify that by setting `.container {text-align: center;}`.  I think the reason why the button is not centered for button widths less than the container width is that the button is not centered within the container itself.  This problem is masked when the button overflows the container's width.

Answer (score 4):

### The reason that `text-align: center` is not working when you set it on the `button` tag is that property is setting the alignment of the text *within* the button itself.

```css
button {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

### We can prove this by setting the width of the button, and setting `text-align: left`.

```css
button {
 width: 70vw;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

### To center the button, we can have its parent to set to `text-align: center`.

```css
div {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
<div>
```

### Additionally, we can set the button to `display: block;` and apply `margin: 0 auto`. This saves us from having to wrap the button within a container element.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```